# Component shows for a brief moment before redirecting in react router v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a small issue I'm not able to fix. In my react app I use react-router v6 and I have to following routes:

```
    <Route path="/" element={<App />} />
    <Route path=":id" element={<CharacterDetails/>} />
    <Route path="*" element={<Navigate replace to="/" />} />
```

As you can see, I have a route that needs an **id**. This works fine as long as I provide an existing Id so that **CharacterDetails** component fetches some data successfully. However, if I pass some random text in the **URL** like **"localhost:3000/randomText**" the **CharacterDetails** component still shows for a brief second till the **useEffect** fires to determine that the request is a 404 and only after that it redirects me to the **App** component.

How can I check if the URL provided should indeed return some data before rendering the component ? and redirect to the App component directly (without the flickering of the **CharacterDetails** component) when it is not a valid URL

Thanks!

EDIT: I'm not sure if this is a router issue or should I do it at the component level, I'm waiting for suggestions

EDIT2: Component code

```
const CharacterDetails = () => {
  const { id } = useParams<string>();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(characterReducer, initialState);
  const { data, episodes, loading } = state;

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async (id: string) => {
      dispatch({ type: "LOADING_START" })
      try {
        let response = await getSingleCharacterData(id);
        let URLs = response.data.episode;
        let listOfEpisodes = await getEpisodeName(URLs);
        dispatch({
          type: "FETCH_SUCCESS",
          payload: { data: response.data, episodeList: listOfEpisodes },
        });
        dispatch({ type: "LOADING_OVER" })
      } catch (error) {
        dispatch({ type: "LOADING_OVER" })
        navigate("/");
      }
    };

    if (id) fetchData(id);
  }, [id, navigate]);

  return ( 
    <CharacterDetailsContainer>
    {loading ? <Loading /> :
      data && ( 
         <div> </div> 
    )}
    </CharacterDetailsContainer>
}
```

Comment: Hey there! Can you please also include the code for the component itself? It may not be a react router issue if it renders for a brief moment first.

Comment: @AmitMaraj see edit

Comment: It looks like you're swallowing any errors (after you catch it) and then navigating to "/". Is your API call returning some error? You can check by console.logging the error and then commenting the navigate function for the time being to debug. On another note, based on your JSX, you could be trying to render something that isn't available. If you include the JSX, i can take a look at that as well!

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an issue with the router/routes, it's something that routed components need to handle.

In the `CharacterDetails` component use some "loading" state to conditionally render `null` or some loading indicator while the `id` path param is validated. Note that "loading" needs to be the initial state so the code isn't leaking any initial non-loading UI, waiting until the `useEffect` hook runs at the end of the initial render to `dispatch({ type: "LOADING_START" })` is too late unless the initial redux state has it set true.

Example:

```
const CharacterDetails = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    // logic to validate id param
    if (is404) {
      navigate("/404", { replace: true }); // redirect
    } else {
      setIsLoading(false); // clear loading state so page content renders
    }
  }, [id]);

  if (isLoading) {
    return null; // or loading spinner/etc...
  }

  return page content
};
```

Your code:

```
const CharacterDetails = () => {
  const { id } = useParams<string>();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState<boolean>(true); // <-- initially true

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(characterReducer, initialState);
  const { data, episodes } = state;

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async (id: string) => {
      setIsLoading(true);
      dispatch({ type: "LOADING_START" });
      try {
        let response = await getSingleCharacterData(id);
        let URLs = response.data.episode;
        let listOfEpisodes = await getEpisodeName(URLs);
        dispatch({
          type: "FETCH_SUCCESS",
          payload: { data: response.data, episodeList: listOfEpisodes },
        });
        setIsLoading(false);
      } catch (error) {
        // handle any errors, etc...

        // redirect home
        navigate("/", { replace: true });
      } finally {
        dispatch({ type: "LOADING_OVER" });
      }
    };

    if (id) fetchData(id);
  }, [id, navigate]);

  if (isLoading) {
    return null; // or loading spinner/etc...
  }

  return ( <some JSX> )
}
```

Comment: i added the code of the component. I do just that, I load a spinner while the request is being handled and based on the result i display it or redirect the user. My question was if theres a way to not show the page at all if the parameter in the URL is not correct

Comment: @CosminMocanu No... the route was already matched and this component already mounted. `react-router-dom` doesn't really handle URL path validation. The best you could likely do is to abstract the URL path validation into a wrapper component or HOC that handles conditionally rendering a loading indicator while the URL  path is validated, to make the code a bit more **DRY**.

Comment: @CosminMocanu Just FYI, I updated my answer to add a note that the loading "state" needs to be initially true when the routed component mounts so there isn't a "blip" of rendering the content before the `useEffect` hook runs and starts any path validation process.

Comment: thanks, the same approach i already had in place. The 'flickering' was more about showing the loading spinner even when the id provided is wrong (i wanted to redirect the user directly without even showing the spinner for a second)
Thanks for the insights

Comment: @CosminMocanu I see. Do you have any way to fetch valid ids prior to a user clicking on a link that uses it? The idea being to know ahead of time what can be validly linked to and explicitly render routes for them. Any id that doesn't have a route associated to it will not be matched.

Comment: yea but this is not optimal, if u have a large number of records received from the api for example

Comment: @CosminMocanu How many records are you discussing here? Millions? From what I can see these are basically your two options: (1) "prefetch" all valid ids and form valid routes for each, or (2) handle any id dynamically and check the id each time and conditionally wait for validation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [useParams](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams) hook in the child.

```
const acceptableIDs = ["dog", "cat"];
function CharacterDetails() {
  let { id } = useParams();
  return acceptableIDs.includes(id) ? (
    <div>
      <h3>ID: {id}</h3>
    </div>
  ) : null; // render nothing or redirect
}
```

If it takes too long to check if the ID is valid, you could show a transition.

Note this is business logic and should probably not bleed into the router.

Comment: i just tested this and it kinda works but in a use case where u have lots of records in a db, you need to do a request to the server in order to get all the ids for all the records and to add them to an array in order for this to work and if u have many records in a db, the time needed to get all the ids will slow down the app drastically

Comment: Yes. If that is the case you should make an async call to check if the ID is valid, and show a "waiting" animation/page until it returns.